# Write a function which accepts an array of integers and returns a new array the two integers that appear most frequently

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, dictionary

**Write a function which accepts an array of integers and returns a new array the two integers that appear most frequently.**

Function currently accepts array input and converts it to dictionary object.

[3,3,1,2,1,1,4,4,4,4] ==> {3: 2, 1: 3, 2: 1, 4: 4}

*How do I sort the dictionary by value and **return the two highest value keys** in a new array? Ex. [4,1]*

```
def majority_element_top_two(arr):
  int_dict = {}    

  for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] not in int_dict:  
      int_dict[arr[i]] = 1
  else:                       
    int_dict[arr[i]] += 1     

return int_dict

print(majority_element_top_two([3,3,1,2,1,1,4,4,4,4]))
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DmoI.jpg)

Comment: sort dictionary by value => a lot of matches here on SO, return the two highest value keys => reverse the mapping and get the keys

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
def majority_element_top_two(arr):
    int_dict = {}    
    for i in arr:
        if i not in int_dict:  
            int_dict[i] = 1
        else:                       
            int_dict[i] += 1     
    return list({k: v for k, v in sorted(int_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)}.keys())[:2]

print(majority_element_top_two([3,3,1,2,1,1,4,4,4,4]))
```

result:

```
[4, 1]
```

Comment: The solution was perfect. Thank you.

Just curious, could you further explain the return statement?

Comment: sort dictionary by value, then get sorted dict's `keys()`, change it into `list`,use `[:2]` slice function to get highest value. @Dominic Holder